# Should this char be unsigned?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, character-encoding, char

I found some confusing code during code review and am a bit puzzled. Doing some research I found this situation. I wrote this sample of code to highlight the problem

```
char d = '©';// this is -87,the copyright symbol , (actually its 169 unsigned)
if(ispunct(d)) // will assert. 
{           
}
```

so, the programmer who was bug fixing, did the following:

```
char d = '©';// this is -87,the copyright symbol , (actually its 169 unsigned)
if(ispunct((unsigned char)d)) // will not assert, because it will be 169.
{           
}
```

My question is whether it is OK to make the `char` unsigned ? Ideally, I wouldn't use `char` but use a Unicode char to avoid this kinds of problem, but the software is very old and wont be reengineered any time soon.

I am using Visual Studio 2008. `ispunct()` can be found in `ctype.h`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cast is correct in this case. From [`man ispunct`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ispunct&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+7.2-RELEASE&format=html):

> The `ispunct()` function tests for any printing character except for space
>   (`' '`) or a character for which `isalnum(3)` is `true`.  The value of the
>   argument must be representable as an `unsigned char` or the value of `EOF`.

Comment: The same is true of the rest of the functions in the same family - eg `isalpha()`, `toupper()` and so on.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use `ispunct`, then there's no way around it.

```
_ASSERTE((unsigned)(c + 1) <= 256);
```

That's what caused the assertion to fail and hence the cast is appropriate.

Comment: i found that assert as well, thats why it raised a red flag in my review process. I cant see why its done within crtdbg.h

Answer (score 2):

It's perfectly legitimate to do the cast. I believe in C variables are signed by default but the cast makes it useable.

Comment: Actually, whether a `char` is signed or not is implementation-defined.